# Can the tooltips of the X axis be customised?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have to implement some graphs in a project I am building. I am currently studying what graph solutions I have, as I do not plan to code the graphs from scratch.

I ran into GraphJS and it seems to have everything I need. I should mention that the graphs are not complex in data they hadnel, but in the way they looks. Therefore we reach the question: can the tooltips of the axis be customised? I have to implement something like this [image: this]

Better said, I need every second day in a 30 days span to not be displayed, but in its place to be shown a grey line. It is possible to achieve something like this with ChartJS?

I have read the documentation, I have not wrote any code as I am looking to find the proper library to use. On the same note, I do not seek an answer from someone providing me code, merely a "yes" or a "no".